# Где найти информацию, исходники C++ по отскокам тел?

Tags: 2d, c++

Здравствуйте, подскажите хороший ресурс или книгу, можно исходники, про отскоки тел в 2d. Про квадратные тела я наслышан и читал много. А как задать отскок шара об наклонную прямую? Может есть библиотеки некие? Только не надо рекомендовать DirectX и OpenGL. Спасибо.

Comment: Тут лучше всего поможет учебник по физике 10-11 класс.

Comment: Мне нужен алгоритм,... У меня шар то прилипал к стене, то отскакивал точно по построенной прямой отскока, но в этом случае на его отскок никак не повлиять... Вообщем деревянно всё получается, не как в жизни, даже не близко..

Comment: Прилипать (при упругом взаимодействии) никак не может (какая-то ошибка в программе). Кстати, Вы наверняка учли, что точка касания шара и наклонной **это не точка**, где напрвление движения шара (по его центру) пересекается с Вашей наклонной.

А что Вы имеете в виду под "повлиять на его отскок" ? Изменение положения прямой в **процессе** отскока ? Тогда надо вводить массы и деформацию тел (во время взаимодействия) т.е. моделировать что-то типа пружинок. И контакт получается не мгновенным.

В жизни еще вращение шара (сила трения при контакте) на направление отскока влияет.

Answer (score 5):

Например Вы отрабатываете перемещения тел в системе через промежутки времени. В некий момент времени расстояние от центра шара до прямой (стенки) станет меньше либо равно 0, это   значит, что произошло столкновение. Координаты окружности не изменятся, изменится только направление движения шара. Он отскочит под тем же углом, что и каснулся. Как луч света, или вроде того.
Если окружность каснется двух или более стен одновременно, то углом отражения будет перпендикуляр к отрезку, соединяющему две крайние точки касания (точно не помню, но вроде бы так).

Answer (score 1):

Даю направление : если для тел - ищи "C++ Ragdoll (2D/3D)", если для шаров - ищи базовые курсы по физике